# Func delegate used as a parameter

Tags: c#, delegates

I am trying to understand what the code below actually does.

We have `Submit` method that returns `void` and takes two arguments:

- Delegate d
- Unrestricted amount of any arguments

Then we call `Submit` method with arguments.

This part of code I do not understand.

```
void Submit(Delegate d, params object[] arguments)
{
    ServiceQueue.Get.Submit(d, arguments);
}

Submit(new Func<BusinessMetadataQueryDataContract,
            AsyncCallback,
            object,
            IAsyncResult>(
                this.Channel.BeginBusinessMetadataGet),
                contract,
                new AsyncCallback(
                    (iar) =>
                    {
                        BusinessMetadataDataContract outContract = null;
                        Action<Exception, OpusReturnType> response =
                            (e, ort) =>
                            {
                                SilverlightClient.UIThread.Run(() =>
                                {
                                    this.BusinessMetadataGetActionCompleted(this,
                                        new ActionCompletedEventArgs<BusinessMetadataDataContract>(
                                            ort,
                                            outContract,
                                            e,
                                            false,
                                            asyncState));
                                });
                            };

                        try
                        {
                            response(null,
                                this.Channel.EndBusinessMetadataGet(
                                    out outContract,
                                    iar));
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            response(e,
                                new OpusReturnType());
                        }
                    }),
                asyncState);
```

`Func` method takes three arguments and returns value.

So we have arguments of type:

- BusinessMetadataQueryDataContract
- AsyncCallback
- object

and we have return type:

- IAsyncResult

Then we have: `(this.Channel.BeginBusinessMetadataGet),`

I do not understand it. What is it doing here? I was expecting an opening bracket `(` and a first parameter of type `BusinessMetadataQueryDataContract`, instead I get `(this.Channel.BeginBusinessMetadataGet)` and expected parameter is positioned on the second position.

I must be missing something here.

Any help? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this.Channel.BeginBusinessMetadataGet is the actual delegate, which have the signature that you describe. So the first argument (Delegate d) is this:

```
new Func<BusinessMetadataQueryDataContract,
            AsyncCallback,
            object,
            IAsyncResult>(
   this.Channel.BeginBusinessMetadataGet)
```

this creates a delegate from the method BeginBusinessMetadataGet. After this are all the parameters that will be used by the delegate.

Comment: Why would someone want to create delegate from a method? For me delegates are something like patterns which some methods follow. How does it work here?

Comment: Delegates are "patterns" in a way, but they are types as any other type in the language. The thing with creating a delegate from a method is common and before lamda expressions were more or less the only way to do it. There are situations where you could use just the method as a parameter though, but I'm not sure that is applicable in your situation, I would need to see more of your code for that.

Comment: Ok... so we can say that method let's say ABC is a delegate from now on? I do not get it...

Comment: A delegate is a "container" for methods, so methods can be assigned to delegate variables. The same as strings can be assigned to string variables. So the method ABC can be assigned to a delegate variable with the correct signature, e. g Func<> or the generic Delegate that can be assigned any method independent of signature.

Comment: Can you think about any reason why we need `(this.Channel.BeginBusinessMetadataGet)` here? When I comment it out I get error: `Method name expected`

Comment: Yes, you need this to create the delegate. What you can try is to remove everything but "this.Channel.BeginBusinessMetadataGet" so the call would look something like:   Submit(this.Channel.BeginBusinessMetadataGet,
                contract, ...  But I'm not sure it will compile either.